# Loop for setting columnnames/data in C# excel export

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export

I'm fairly new to C#/.net and I'm looking for a cleaner way to set columnnames and data for a Excel export.

The code below works, but like I said, I'm looking for a better way to do this (possibly in a loop or something)?

```cs
            var gw = new RequestGateway(); 
            var results = gw.GetResultsForExcelExport(customerId).ToList();            
            var columnnames = gw.GetColumnNamesForExcelExport(languageCode).First();

            ExcelPackage Ep = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet Sheet = Ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");
            Sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = columnnames.ordno;
            Sheet.Cells["B1"].Value = columnnames.barcode;
            Sheet.Cells["C1"].Value = columnnames.customerDescription;
            Sheet.Cells["D1"].Value = columnnames.customerLabel;
            Sheet.Cells["E1"].Value = columnnames.itemCode;
            Sheet.Cells["F1"].Value = columnnames.anaCode;
            Sheet.Cells["G1"].Value = columnnames.testname;
            Sheet.Cells["H1"].Value = columnnames.analyte;
            Sheet.Cells["I1"].Value = columnnames.result;
            Sheet.Cells["J1"].Value = columnnames.resultUnit;
            Sheet.Cells["K1"].Value = columnnames.resultComment;
            Sheet.Cells["L1"].Value = columnnames.matrix;
            Sheet.Cells["M1"].Value = columnnames.samplingDate;
            Sheet.Cells["N1"].Value = columnnames.productionDate;
            Sheet.Cells["O1"].Value = columnnames.folderNo;
            Sheet.Cells["P1"].Value = columnnames.dateReceived;
            Sheet.Cells["Q1"].Value = columnnames.customerReference;
            Sheet.Cells["R1"].Value = columnnames.reportDate;
            int row = 2;

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", row)].Value = result.ordno;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", row)].Value = result.barcode;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", row)].Value = result.customerDescription;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", row)].Value = result.customerLabel;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", row)].Value = result.itemCode;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("F{0}", row)].Value = result.anaCode;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("G{0}", row)].Value = result.testname;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("H{0}", row)].Value = result.analyte;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("I{0}", row)].Value = result.result;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("J{0}", row)].Value = result.resultUnit;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("K{0}", row)].Value = result.resultComment;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("L{0}", row)].Value = result.matrix;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("M{0}", row)].Value = result.samplingDate;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("N{0}", row)].Value = result.productionDate;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("O{0}", row)].Value = result.folderNo;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("P{0}", row)].Value = result.dateReceived;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("Q{0}", row)].Value = result.customerReference;
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("R{0}", row)].Value = result.reportDate;
                row++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be used extension to class Worksheet for example

```
public static void InsertTableRow(this Worksheet XlWorksheet, string[] args, int rowIndex = 1, int columnStartIndex = 1)
    {            
        int i = columnStartIndex;
        Range tmpRange;            
        foreach (string row in args)
        {
            tmpRange = XlWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex, i] as Range;                 
            tmpRange.Value2 = row;  
            i++;
        }           
    }
```